# The Present Simple tense use

Tags: tenses, time, present-tense, present-progressive

I would like to know why this tense is used instead of the present continuous in the following examples:

1. As we speak (instead of - as we are speaking) something is taking place
2. He joins us from (instead of - he is joining us), (the name of a place - Paris, London) The TV anchor is introducing a guest

Comment: One assumes that 'As we speak' is classed as an idiom by [Farlex](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/as+we+speak) and [McGraw-Hill](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/as+we+speak) which include it in their Idioms Dictionaries. This means that there is some unusual grammar involved, as the words have their usual meanings (possibly broadened). But the punctive sense (right now) befits the meaning in any case. And surely the punctive (here he is, [introduced by me] at this very moment!) sense also works with the fixed phrase 'X joins us from'.

Comment: It is possible to use the present tense to refer to the present instant. Generally the progressive is also possible in these contexts.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth As for the "As we speak" I agree, but what about the second example? Why does TV anchors say - he/she joins us, instead of - he/she is joining us from (somewhere)? Or both variants are acceptable?

Comment: I can't see a problem, but [these Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?year_end=2019&year_start=1800&content=he+joins+us+from%2Che+is+joining+us+from&smoothing=3&corpus=26&direct_url=t1%3B%2Che%20joins%20us%20from%3B%2Cc0) suggest that '[he] joins us from' is the more idiomatic.

Comment: [These Google ngrams also](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?year_end=2019&year_start=1800&content=join+us+from%2Care+joining+us+from%2Cjoins+us+from%2Cis+joining+us+from&smoothing=3&corpus=26&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cjoin%20us%20from%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Care%20joining%20us%20from%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cjoins%20us%20from%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20joining%20us%20from%3B%2Cc0) show preference for the present simple variant.

Comment: The MGH and Farlex notion that “as we speak” (and, presumably, similar constructs) is idiom seems absurd. There are countless consistently formed examples: as rain falls it freezes; as time passes, we age; as people arrive they are served; and so on. No restrictive formalist grammatical rule can stand in the face of such an onslaught.

Comment: @Anton What you are referring to in your comment is actually a grammatical structure. We use it when we describe two things that happen at the same time. It's most commonly used for two continuing processes that happen together; as something happens, something else happens. But as it seems, it`s not canonical or universal. We can use it with the present continuous tense. As something happens, something is happening/taking a place. For instance, as we speak, the president is holding a news briefing, etc.

Comment: @Beqa Agreed. Thanks for clarification.

Comment: @Anton 'While we are dithering, war is getting closer' would sound at best odd with 'dither' for 'are dithering'. And the present continuous seems more fitting here, dithering being time-consuming (durative). I agree though that there are too many commonly used examples of _as/while + present simple + ..._ for this to be classed as multiple idioms rather than an accepted fairly general usage. So, perversely, it's idiomatic.